# (Desde mac (Bigsur 11.7.2)). IDLE no aparece en aplicaciones y no me ofrece la opción "abrir con" IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, macos, idle, homebrew

Todo esto es desde `bigsur 11.7.2`

1. He instalado `Xcode 13.2` (compatible con `Bigsur 11.7.2`) y sus `Command line tools`.
2. He instalado `homebrew` desde https://brew.sh/index_es.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

3. He instalado `python`

```
brew install python
```

> 3.1 He creado un fichero `.zshrc` en `/usr/jose` y he añadido el enlace simbólico al PATH.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Hasta aquí todo ok: el python predeterminado ya es `python3.10`.

### Problema:

Ni `IDLE`ni `Python Launcher`se han incorporado en `Aplicaciones`.

He buscado `IDLE`en el sistema en lo he encontrado en:

`/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/idle3.10`, pero al clicar dos veces me arroja el siguiente error:
`" No hay ninguna aplicación definida para abrir el documento “idle3.10”"`.

He buscado y he entendido que podría ser debido a que necesitase tener instalado `tkinter` para abrir `idle` así que lo he instalado

```
brew instal python-tk@3.10
```

y ahora en la terminal si escribo

```
idle
```

me abre IDLE. Bien.
Pero entiendo que algo no está bien porque dos motivos:

1: Sigue sin ofrecerme la opción de `"abrir con"` `idle` en los `archivos.py`.
2: Sigue sin aparecerme el icono de `idle` en `aplicaciones`.
3: En los `archivos.py` no me aparece el icono de `python`.